# Custom template for Essential grid posts Wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I use Essential Grid Posts plugin, I would like to create a custom template for posts I create in Ess. Grid Posts

Usually to create custom template for post that belong to a category I use the following code:

```
<?php

$post = $wp_query->post;

if ( in_category('3') ) {

include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-1.php');

} elseif ( in_category('7') ) {

include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-2.php');

} else {

include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-default.php');

}

?>
```

But it doesn't work with the id category of Essential grid post. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repost from FAQ plugin:

> Duplicate your theme's "single.php" and/or "archive.php" file, and
>   rename it to one of the following: single-essential_grid.php
>   archive-essential_grid.php

http://www.themepunch.com/faq/apply-specific-theme-template-file-to-ess-grid-posts-advanced/